# How to solve ADFS timeout while trying to login

Tags: adfs

I have configured ADFS server and from 50 attempts to login I got successfully logged in for 5 times.

For 95 times I get error connection timeout out.
[image]

There is nothing in event viewer.

Server is "Windows Server 2012 R2"

Has anybody idea what could be a problem?

Tried to logged from different computers, countries and browsers, same issue.

Thank you

P.S. If If you have any other question please ask.

**UPDATE 1:**

Structure:
Web server (Ubuntu) -> ADFS Server -> ADFS client login server

Communication should go:
Web server (Ubuntu) (S1) -> ADFS Server (S2) -> ADFS client login server(S3) -> ADFS server(S2) -> Web server(S1)

If fails, always fails on relation (S3) -> (S2) but when client is returning from his login server.

**UPDATE 2:**

Using Fiddler I get header status 504 and this message:
"[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes."

Comment: Have you checked that if the ADFS service name (federation.domain.com) can be resolved to the WAP external IP address successfully? Did you use  ADFS farm in your scenario? If so, you should check if each ADFS node in this farm works correctly. Also, on the ADFS server, you can try to examine the event logs in the Applications and Services log->ADFS Tracing-> Debug(enable debug log first).

Comment: @LongfeiSun-MSFT - improved explanation in my Question

Comment: I think there should be something in the event logs of ADFS server, have you checked it again (ADFS admin logs and debug logs)? If you try to login in the application from the Intranet, will it works successfully each time?